# Display Toast message in Presentation Display with presentation context

Tags: android

I want to show two different toasts in Main Display and Presentation Display.

I use following code to show toast

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No HDMI Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

where, `getContext()` is as below

```
public Context getContext() {
        if (presentation != null) {   //presentation object
            return(presentation.getContext());
        }

        return(getActivity());
    }
```

The problem is Toast is not shown in Presentation display, which is a HDMI screen.

How this could be achieved any help / hint is of very help...

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible without writing your own `Toast` Class. I've checked out the source code of Toast, and from the passed context it gets the Application context, so that's why the toast is always rendered in the primary display:

From `Toast.java` source code (example http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.4_r1-robolectric-0/android/widget/Toast.java)

```
373        public void handleShow() {
.
.
380                Context context = mView.getContext().getApplicationContext();
.
384                mWM = (WindowManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
.
.
405                mWM.addView(mView, mParams);
```

Good news are, I have written myself an el-cheapo version of `Toast`, fixed to run in different displays. It's not a drop-in replacement nor it has fancy animations, but has other cool features such as persistent toasts and custom timing. And you can customize it yourself easily to fit your application style.

Here it goes:

```
package com.regaliz.custom;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * A Toast-like class that can be used across different displays, 
 * and show permanent and custom-timed notifications.
 *
 * Rodolfo Lopez 2016 - Freeware 
 *
 * Usage:
 * 
 * 1) Create the object: 
 *
 *    Tostada mTostada = new Tostada(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 50);
 *
 * 2) Assign a context. You can dynamically change the context to 
 * the Tostada object in the case of a display change without the
 * need to create another object.
 *
 *    mTostada.setContext(context);
 *
 * 3) Start toasting!
 *
 *    mTostada.makeText("hi!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
 *    mTostada.makeText("hi!", 0);
 *    - You can use "0" to make the Toast persistent
 *    - Toasts are NOT QUEUED: If a toast is visible, the text will
 * be replaced and the new timeout set. This just fits my use case.
 * 
 * 4) call setContext(null) in the case of multi-context use, 
 * for example, when you close a presentation display, so a 
 * reference to an invalid context is not kept. Or just change to 
 * a valid context.
 *
 */

public class Tostada {

    private TextView mView;
    private WindowManager mWM;
    private final WindowManager.LayoutParams mParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    private Context mContext;

    /**
     * Creates a Tostada with a gravity ana an offset x, y
     *
     * @param offsetX The X offset in pixels to apply to the gravity's location.
     * @param offsetY The Y offset in pixels to apply to the gravity's location.
     * @paran gravity The gravity constant
     */

    public Tostada(int gravity, int offsetX, int offsetY) {

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mParams;
        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        params.windowAnimations = 0;
        params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
        params.setTitle("Toast");
        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE;

        mParams.gravity = gravity;
        mParams.x = offsetX;
        mParams.y = offsetY;
        mParams.verticalMargin = 0;
        mParams.horizontalMargin = 0;

    }

    /**
     * Assign the Tostada context. It can be a Presentation context. Remember to call setContext(null)
     * to clear the stored context when you no longer need this class, otherwise memory leaks can occur.
     *
     * @param context The context where the Tostada will be rendered
     */

    public void setContext(Context context) {

        if (mContext != null) {
            if (mContext == context) {
                // re - assigning same context, just return
                return;
            }
            handleHide();
        }

        mContext = context;

        if (context == null) {

            mView = null;
            return;
        }

        mParams.packageName = context.getPackageName();

        // I use a plain TextView with default styling.
        // you can customize it here

        mView = new TextView(context);

        mWM = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

    }

    private Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handleHide();
        }
    };

    public void makeText(String text, int timeout) {

        if (mContext == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("You must assign a context to this Tostada before it vcan be used");

        // remove old timer for an ongoing tostada, if any
        mView.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);

        mView.setText(text);

        // Add the view to the window manager, if not already added
        if (mView.getParent() == null)
            mWM.addView(mView, mParams);

        // schedule for removal

        if (timeout > 0)
            mView.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, timeout);
    }

    private void handleHide() {

        // remove the view if added
        if (mView.getParent() != null)
            mWM.removeView(mView);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the source code. It has to be modular enough to accept the context passed :(

Comment: yeah its just an skeleton, my use case is very specific, but i prefer to post the very basics so you can tweak it to your needs instead of adding stuff not related to the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting API level >= 30, you can also use [`Context.createWindowContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#createWindowContext(int,%20android.os.Bundle)) with the platform's Toast class. Like this:

```
/* 
   Just for completeness: find first secondary display
*/
int displayId = 0;
final DisplayManager dm = getSystemService(DisplayManager.class);
Display[] displays = dm.getDisplays();
for (Display d : displays) {
    if(d.getDisplayId() != 0) {
        displayId = d.getDisplayId();
        break;
    }
}
final Display display = dm.getDisplay(displayId);

/*
   Now, the bread and butter: we use the display to create a display context,
   from which we create a window context,
   this in turn is used to create the Toast
*/
final Context windowContext = createDisplayContext(display)
                 .createWindowContext(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST, null);

Toast.makeText(windowContext, "yo 2nd display", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```